# Infimum and Supremum of set

Tags: real-analysis

Find the infimum and supremum of set
{1/2,3/4,7/8,15/16}

I believe the answer is Infimum : 1/2 and supremum is Infinity

Still not sure of Infimum.

Comment: Are you taking about a *finite* set with 4 elements?

Comment: Do you acutally mean the set $\{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}\}$ for each natural number $n$ or do you mean just the four element set?

Answer (score 1):

The supremum is 15/16 and the infimum is 1/2. If you meant for this to be an infinite sequence then the supremum is 1 and the infimum is still 1/2.